# Transversality condition for an optimal control problem

Tags: calculus-of-variations, optimal-control, transversality

Let the optimal control problem: $$\max \int_a^bF(t,x(t),u(t))dt$$
$$x'(t)=g(t,x(t),u(t)) \; for \; all \; t\in [a,b]$$
$$x(a)=A$$
$$x(b)\geq0.$$

Unising the maximum principle and the adjoint state $p(.)$

I want to prove the following transverality condition :

$$p(b)\geq0$$
$$p(b)x(b)=0$$

Comment: I do not see any question. What do you have tried?